# Getting "extension would be able to read and alter webpages..." on Safari Extensions

Tags: app-store, safari-extension, mac-app-store

I'm creating a safari extension that manipulates DOM for a good purpose & runs smoothly on firefox and chrome. However, when I try to upload it in debug mode before launching I get:

*This extension would be able to read and alter webpages and see your browsing history on this website. This could include sensitive information, including passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards.*

which extensions that are alike my extensions on safari don't even face such warning being asked from their user. What shall I do to prevent such a thing from getting asked just like similar extensions are doing? I have a feeling I'm calling one extra unnecessary API?
Would be happy to provide the necessary code for look up upon request.